# Python program can run on VS code but not on Mac's Terminal

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I encounter a very bizarre response when I try to execute my python code with the Terminal on Mac OS. However, it is normal on Visual Studio Code interpreter.

The error message complains about the existence of the module `pyvisa`. However, it is well installed. This is the full log:

```
Last login: Sat May 15 15:30:04 on ttys000
pokfung@pn-204-230 g13jv % pip3 show pyvisa
Name: PyVISA
Version: 1.11.3
Summary: Python VISA bindings for GPIB, RS232, TCPIP and USB instruments
Home-page: https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa
Author: Torsten Bronger, Gregor Thalhammer
Author-email: bronger@physik.rwth-aachen.de
License: MIT License
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: typing-extensions
Required-by: 
pokfung@pn-204-230 g13jv % python gui.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    from subpage import nav, setting
  File "/Users/pokfung/Documents/Coding/JVgui/g13jv/subpage/nav.py", line 3, in <module>
    from subpage import navM
  File "/Users/pokfung/Documents/Coding/JVgui/g13jv/subpage/navM.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyvisa
ImportError: No module named pyvisa
```

UPDATE: I discovered that the command `python` actually points to the 2.7.6 distribution and `python3` works as I expect.

Comment: My guess is that your `pip3` and `python` don't point to the same python distribution. Could you run `which pip3` and `which python`?

Comment: ```pokfung@pn-204-230 g13jv % which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3
pokfung@pn-204-230 g13jv % which python
/usr/bin/python``` You are right. May I ask how I can unify them?

Comment: You can rename python(/usr/bin/python) to python2, and python3(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/python3) to python